# How I create a private key for my Laravel application

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to get started with the latest Laravel. I had just created my Laravel from the command line via the command *composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-app*

I have installed Homestead and now trying to create Vagrant box with the command

```
 vagrant up
```

I'm getting the error, c*heck your Homestead.yaml (or Homestead.jso) file, the path to your private key does not exist*

To which I ran the command

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now I'm getting the error *Saving key "~/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory*

I'm running Windows 10

Comment: Just go to your user directory (most likely on c:\Users\yourname) and make a new directory ".ssh" (with a leading dot). Then run above command with the path (c:\users\yourname\.ssh\id_rsa) and you are good 

Comment: Pathes in your `homestead.yaml` must be like this: c:/users/foo/.ssh/id_rsa , so with one slash and no backslash ;)

Comment: My PC user is "My PC". The command then becomes C:/Users/MY PC/.ssh/id_rsa. Now I'm getting Too Many arguments. I think it must be because of the space between My PC

Comment: Just wrap the whole c:/... into a quotes, like `"c:/users/..../id_rsa"`, this is default windows command line

Comment: That worked! I now get the message that the key has been created. Thanks so much :-)

Comment: @JunDolor you say "that worked". which of the above worked for you? Thanks